# groupSuppressAutoColumn not working with dynamic columnDef - ag-grid angular

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-grouping

I am trying to create custom rowGrouping using 'agGroupCellRenderer'. But but after creating new row group using row group panel drag feature, grid data disappears.

https://plnkr.co/edit/cGmrnc2LecpFhttY?preview

am trying to update columnDef

```
columnRowGroupChanged(event) {

this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Country',
    minWidth: 200,
    showRowGroup: 'country',
    cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Year',
    minWidth: 200,
    showRowGroup: 'year',
    cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'athlete',
    minWidth: 200,
    showRowGroup: 'athlete',
    cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
  },
  {
    field: 'country',
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'year',
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'athlete',
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true,
  },
  { field: 'gold' },
  { field: 'silver' },
  { field: 'bronze' },
];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Check Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reo7d.png)

```
  this.gridColumnApi.purgeInfiniteCache();
   this.columnDefs = [
     {
       headerName: 'Country',
       minWidth: 200,
       showRowGroup: 'country',
       cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
     },
     {
       headerName: 'Year',
       minWidth: 200,
       showRowGroup: 'year',
       cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
     },
     {
       headerName: 'athlete',
       minWidth: 200,
       showRowGroup: 'athlete',
       cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
     },
     {
       field: 'country',
       rowGroup: true,
       hide: true,
     },
     {
       field: 'year',
       rowGroup: true,
       hide: true,
     },
     {
       field: 'athlete',
       rowGroup: true,
       hide: true,
     },
     { field: 'gold' },
     { field: 'silver' },
     { field: 'bronze' },
   ];
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).